# Azure Java "Web app with MySQL in-app" having Communications link failure to database

Tags: java, mysql, azure, spring-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a java spring-mvc web app into azure, but having trouble on connecting the MySQL in-app.

After deployed, I have updated the host, port, username and password in my xml according to the connection string in

> /data/mysql/MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.txt

Any helps on this?
A side question, anyone how to get the connection string in java? so that if the port number changed, will not need to update the xml.

Encounter this error:

```
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:394)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:474)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:484)
    jbr.springmvc.dao.UserDaoImpl.validateUser(UserDaoImpl.java:44)
    jbr.springmvc.service.UserServiceImpl.validateUser(UserServiceImpl.java:26)
    jbr.springmvc.controller.LoginController.loginProcess(LoginController.java:28)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2209)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
    com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:196)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:159)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:394)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:474)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:484)
    jbr.springmvc.dao.UserDaoImpl.validateUser(UserDaoImpl.java:44)
    jbr.springmvc.service.UserServiceImpl.validateUser(UserServiceImpl.java:26)
    jbr.springmvc.controller.LoginController.loginProcess(LoginController.java:28)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:343)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2132)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
    com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:196)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:159)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:394)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:474)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:484)
    jbr.springmvc.dao.UserDaoImpl.validateUser(UserDaoImpl.java:44)
    jbr.springmvc.service.UserServiceImpl.validateUser(UserServiceImpl.java:26)
    jbr.springmvc.controller.LoginController.loginProcess(LoginController.java:28)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:292)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2132)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
    com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:196)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:159)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:394)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:474)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:484)
    jbr.springmvc.dao.UserDaoImpl.validateUser(UserDaoImpl.java:44)
    jbr.springmvc.service.UserServiceImpl.validateUser(UserServiceImpl.java:26)
    jbr.springmvc.controller.LoginController.loginProcess(LoginController.java:28)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

The web app is working fine in my local, able to connect and insert data into database.

Appreciate the helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced similar issue. Finally found out that, I must use latest version of MySQL-connector-java jar.
I was using 5.1.6 version before.. the error was gone after upgrading to 5.1.30 version or later

Comment: Many thanks Venky, after upgraded to 5.1.30 version connector it work.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your description of your issue, it seems that you've written the `MySql in-app` configuration information as a **constant** in your xml file.

However,it's important to know that the `port` in the configuration parameters changes randomly as the application restarts. So you need to configure connectString **dynamically**.

You could find the configuration information for connection in the `MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.txt` you mentioned.Actually,`MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb` is an environment variable that you could fetch it in the Java via the `getEnv` method.

You could refer to the code below to re-configure your MYSQL connection parameters dynamically.

```
    String connectString = System.getenv("MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb");

    response.getWriter().append("connectString: " + connectString);

    String database = "";
    String port = "";
    String username = "";
    String password = "";

    String[] strArray = connectString.split(";");
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        String[] paramArray = strArray[i].split("=");
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            database = paramArray[1];
            continue;
        case 1:
            port = paramArray[1];
            continue;
        case 2:
            username = paramArray[1];
            continue;
        case 3:
            password = paramArray[1];
            continue;
        }
    }

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + port + "/" + database + "?"
            + "user=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8";

    response.getWriter().append("url:" + url);

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        response.getWriter().append("     connect success");

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "create table student(NO char(20),name varchar(20),primary key(NO))";

        int result = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        response.getWriter().append("     insert result" + result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

---

***Update Answer***

Please check whether `<environmentVariable name="JAVA_OPTS" value="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" />` is configured in your web.config file on Kudu.

> The container needs to be configured for IPv4 traffic only which mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-java-custom-upload).

You could refer to the solutions from this thread [Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql) and get more details about MySql in-app from [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/MySQL-in-app).

Comment: Hi Jay, appreciate your reply, will try it now. Btw, I getting the port number from the MyPHPadmin portal.

Comment: @kenlee Hi ken, waiting your reply of your trying.

Comment: I still hitting the same error in the application after update to use the connection string. Any ideas? To reproduce it, you can go to http://springmvcuser.azurewebsites.net/SpringMvcUser/ and click on the Login and click on the OK button, it will shows the errors.

Comment: Thank you for the updates, But I still encounter the same error, I have followed the instruction in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-java-custom-upload

In my server.xml all have been set to:
Shutdown port = -1
HTTP connector port = ${port.http}
HTTP connector address = "127.0.0.1"
Comment out HTTPS and AJP connectors

catalina.properties file already has java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

I will try check other solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql

Comment: @kenlee Please refer to steps from this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-java-custom-upload and configure web.config file(if it doesn't exist please create it) and re-try.

Comment: sorry for late reply, @jaygong have try with creating we.config file and put it in \wwwroot folder, still getting the same error.

Comment: @kenlee Never mind,I did want to help you to solve this issue. Would you please post your web.config file content?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154425/discussion-between-ken-lee-and-jay-gong).